# Accumulate function from its own output

Tags: python, iterator, accumulate

I've got the following generator, it's a bit like `itertools.accumulate`, except that it takes the next input from the function's own output rather from than an iterable:

```py
def turboaccumulate(f, *, initial):
    x = initial
    while True:
        x = f(x)
        yield x
```

Is anything like this contained in the standard library, or does the Python documentation contain a recommended recipe for this? I was unable to find one in about 20 minutes of searching.

Or, at the very least: **what is this operation called?** (I *highly* doubt "turbo-accumulate" is the **recognized** name for it.)

---

The context of this was an effort to parse the [inscrutable lisp behemoth here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub?oldid=1026719667#Example) into something understandable by mortals, which I got down to:

```py
def blum_blum_shub(p, q, s):
    #assert gcd(p*q, s) == 1
    #assert p % 4 == 3 and q % 4 == 3
    #assert s not in {0, 1}
    M = p * q
    yield from turboaccumulate(lambda x: pow(x, 2, M), initial=s)
```

However, that final function call just looks absolutely goofy, so I'm wondering if it's present in the standard library or at least has a more recognized name.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't have such a built-in as far as I know unfortunately. If you require this functionality, your generator function is probably as clean as you'll get.

`iter`'s less-known second-form *almost* does what you want, but unfortunately, they made it purely side-effectual, which breaks the pattern. To make use of it, you'd need a wrapper similar to this:

```
def fp_iter(f, initial):
    acc = initial
    def wrapper():
        nonlocal acc
        return (acc := f(acc))

    return iter(wrapper, object())

>>> i = fp_iter(lambda n: n + 1, 0)
>>> next(i)
1
>>> next(i)
2
>>> next(i)
3
```

And at that point, I'd just use your generator.

---

It terms of the name of this, I know this as the [`iterate` function](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/iterate) due to my time using Clojure. This resembles [iteration in math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration), so I think that's about as appropriate name as you'll get:

> In mathematics, iteration may refer to the process of iterating a function, i.e. applying a function repeatedly, using the output from one iteration as the input to the next.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `accumulate` to achieve this in some sort of non-standard way:

```
from itertools import accumulate, count

def turboaccumulate(f, initial):
    return accumulate(count(), lambda x, y: f(x), initial=initial)
```

You can use any infinite iterator instead of `count` as its values are ignored (`y` is never used).

Comment: Per your comment in the post (in case the edit gets rejected): `itertools.repeat(None)` is a strong choice for an alternative to `count()` that doesn't create as many unnecessary objects.

Answer (score 0):

The package `more_itertools` contains a function called [`iterate`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.iterate) that does exactly what you implemented as `turboaccumulate`.

See the following example:

```py
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> from more_itertools import iterate
>>> list(islice(iterate(lambda x: 2*x, 1), 10))
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512]
```